# Image flickering upon being repainted by the mouseDragged method

Tags: java, swing, jframe, repaint

As the title suggests, my problem is that I want to be able to drag an image.
In this specific case, I want to drag an image from one JPanel (or rather my own subclass) into another (different) subclass of JPanel. Therefore, I added an `MouseListener` to my JPanel subclass, so that upon clicking a certain area in the panel, an image is chosen to be painted on the JFrame (subclass). Here's some code so you'll understand my problem:

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX();
    int y = e.getY();
    if (x >= 10 && x < 42 && y >= 10 && y < 42) {
        image = barracks;   //barracks is a predefined image, created in the constructor
        dragBuilding = true;
        PixelMain.pixelMain.repaint(); //pixelMain is an instance of the JFrame subclass
    }
}
//irrelevant code, e.g mouseMoved, ...
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if (dragBuilding) {
        //System.out.println("GPanel mouseDragged");
        PixelMain.pixelMain.repaint();
    }
}
```

the JFrame subclass only contains the constructor and the following code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {   //i would have used paintComponent, but it seems like JFrame does not have this method ...?
    super.paint(g);
    if (PixelMain.panelOffense.getDragBuilding()) {  //panelOffense is an instance of the JPanel subclass, getDragBuilding returns a boolean that depends on whether the mouse is held down at the moment
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D tr = new Rectangle2D.Double((int)getMousePosition().getX(), (int)getMousePosition().getY(), 16, 16); //size of the texture
        TexturePaint tp = new TexturePaint(PixelMain.panelOffense.getImg(), tr);
        g2.setPaint(tp);
        Rectangle2D r = (Rectangle2D) new Rectangle((int)getMousePosition().getX(), (int)getMousePosition().getY(), 16, 16); //area to fill with texture
        g2.fill(r);

        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Before you ask - I did move some code to other classes so it's called less often, but that's not the problem. Even if the paint method only draws a rectangle (directly on Graphics g, not Graphics2D), the rectangle flickers.
If anyone could help me figure out a solution, I'd be very thankful!

Note: I know it's probably not very elegant to draw on a JFrame or a subclass of JFrame, but I personally don't know an alternative.
Note 2: According to google/stackoverflow results or threads that I read, I should use a JPanel, which seems to be double-buffered (whatever that is, I didn't really understand that. but then again, it's almost 11 pm here). Hence, I could probably move all my components to a JPanel to solve the issue, but I wanted to try to solve the problem without doing that.
Note 3: Yes, the code belongs to a (strategy) game I'm writing, but considering that the problem is not really related to game development exclusively, I decided to post it here and not at game development stack exchange.

Comment: "whatever that is" It's the reason why the image flickers when you redraw it.

Comment: @AndyTurner i guess you mean it's **absence** is the reason ...?
I'll have a look at it again tomorrow, for now, I'll go to sleep, since I have to go to school in roughly 7 1/2 hours.

Comment: Yes. `JPanel` supports double-buffering, but it isn't enabled by default (because it requires twice the memory).

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `JFrame` is not double buffered, so it could be responsible for generating the flickering. As a general rule you should not override `paint`, but especially of top level containers like `JFrame` and instead, should be using a `JPanel` and overriding it's `paintComponent` method instead

Comment: @AndyTurner I've moved all my components onto a JPanel subclass so the double buffering is enabled, and concerning the flickering, my problem is solved.  
HOWEVER, my image is now painted _behind_ my components on the JPanel (e.g. buttons, panels, ...). Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: nevermind, I found a solution. It seems that in this case, I SHOULD override paint, otherwise the repaint() method draws "behind" components on my panel.